# How can I reference a many-to-many relationship using ID's consisting of sequenced numbers with dash?

Tags: sql, database-design, ids

One "Data" table to many "Comments" table. On many instances the comments apply to a range of data_ids. For example Comments row connects to data_id's (3-60, 90, 100-130). How should the database-design, relationships, and datatypes be implemented. Must be easily accessible ID's for joins, searches, etc.
Seeking to create such a relationship to hold the multiple data_id's on each comment table row.
How would this be implemented, in terms of database structure and datatypes?

Comment: Please include some sample data from both tables.

Comment: Seeking to create such a relationship to hold the multiple data_id's on each comment table row.

Comment: What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship between Data and Comments.  Such relationships require an intermediate "junction" or "mapping" table to implement the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: How would this look, in terms of database structure and datatypes?

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to read/watch about SQL relation types: one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.

In your case if one comment row is linked to many data rows, but data row has only one comment row, you should put comment id in data row (one-to-many).

If comment row is linked to many data rows and data rows can be linked to many comments, you should create a third table with data row id and comment row id to link those (many-to-many).

One-to-many query:

```
SELECT * FROM data
LEFT JOIN comment ON data.comment_id = comment.id
WHERE comment.id = 1
```

One-to-many query

```
SELECT * FROM data
LEFT JOIN data_comment ON data. id = data_comment.data_id
LEFT JOIN comment ON data_comment.comment_id = comment.id
WHERE comment.id = 1
```

"data_comment" being the relation table with data_id and comment_id